# Removing a row if two columns don't match with MySQL

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT follower_id, poster_id, recipient_id
FROM followers
INNER JOIN post on followed_id = poster_id
WHERE follower_id = 1;

returns:

+-------------+-----------+--------------+
| follower_id | poster_id | recipient_id |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
|           1 |         2 |            2 |
|           1 |         2 |            2 |
|           1 |         2 |            2 |
|           1 |         2 |            7 |
+-------------+-----------+--------------+
```

Is there a way to omit the row where poster_id != recipient_id? I need the top 3 rows...

Comment: try adding `and poster_id = recipient_id` to your WHERE clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only need to omit them in results, use the `AND` operator in `WHERE` clause.

```
SELECT follower_id, poster_id, recipient_id
FROM followers
INNER JOIN post on followed_id = poster_id
WHERE follower_id = 1 AND poster_id != recipient_id;
```

Comment: Thanks man, much appreciated. I was trying to make it really complicated, and it turned out to be simple. `... AND poster_id = recipient_id` is what did it.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT follower_id, poster_id, recipient_id
FROM followers
INNER JOIN post on followed_id = poster_id
WHERE follower_id = 1 AND poster_id != recipient_id;
LIMIT 3;
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: You could write it without give me negative feedback!